# C++ pimpl with indirect_value

Tags: c++

After long googling I try to use the proposal [indirect_value](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p1950r1.html) to implement a simple pimpl.

The reason for doing so is to hide "libarchive - archive.h" to the end user, also to be api compatible between releases.

What do you think about this code, it's of course only the impl boilerplate of the full code.

**vfs_archive.h**:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

#include <indirect_value.h>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

namespace ups {

class vfs_archive {
  vfs_archive();
  isocpp_p1950::indirect_value<class vfs_archive_pimpl> pimpl_;

 public:
  vfs_archive(const fs::path& pPath);

  vfs_archive(vfs_archive&& rhs) noexcept;
  vfs_archive(const vfs_archive& rhs);
  vfs_archive& operator=(vfs_archive&& rhs) noexcept;
  vfs_archive& operator=(const vfs_archive& rhs);
  ~vfs_archive();
};

};  // namespace ups
```

**vfs_archive.cpp**

```cpp
#include "vfs_archive.h"

extern "C" {
#include "archive.h"  // libarchive
};

namespace ups {

class vfs_archive_pimpl {
  fs::path path_;
  archive* archive_ = nullptr;

  inline void read_free() {
    archive_ = nullptr;
  };

 public:
  vfs_archive_pimpl() = default;
  explicit vfs_archive_pimpl(fs::path path) : path_(std::move(path)){};
  ~vfs_archive_pimpl() { read_free(); };

  // Move
  vfs_archive_pimpl(vfs_archive_pimpl&& rhs) noexcept = default;
  vfs_archive_pimpl& operator=(vfs_archive_pimpl&& rhs) noexcept = default;

  // Copy
  vfs_archive_pimpl(const vfs_archive_pimpl& rhs) = default;
  vfs_archive_pimpl& operator=(const vfs_archive_pimpl& rhs) = default;

  friend class vfs_archive;
};

vfs_archive::vfs_archive() = default;
vfs_archive::vfs_archive(vfs_archive&& rhs) noexcept = default;
vfs_archive::vfs_archive(const vfs_archive& rhs) = default;
vfs_archive& vfs_archive::operator=(vfs_archive&& rhs) noexcept = default;
vfs_archive& vfs_archive::operator=(const vfs_archive& rhs) = default;
vfs_archive::~vfs_archive() = default;

};  // namespace ups
```

Main reason for asking is that I'm no C++ expert, I want to know if the Copy and Move instruction's will work as is.

But I'm happy with all kind of comments, including code style ones.

The goal of "ups::vfs" (I have no good name for it yet) is to be a fully thread safe replacement of Physicsfs on top of libarchive, it will be part of [UpSpring](https://github.com/techannihilation/upspring) and hopefully other projects of mine and others.

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. What we do here is make insightful observations about working code from a project you have written. We need to know what the code is supposed to do, this is usually in the title and maybe one or two paragraphs of description before the code. We don't review theoretical or pseudo code or example code. Based on the class and method names this code seems to be theoretical in nature. Read https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778 and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You might want to try [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  It's best to describe **what value this code provides to its user**.

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks for giving direct instructions! I added the motivation, what do you think?

Comment: You mentioned UpSpring in a previous revision, but removed it again. Why, was it not relevant? ""The reason for doing so is to hide "libarchive - archive.h" to the end user, also to be api compatible between releases."" Is this a problem you've encountered?

Comment: @Mast I'm implementing this in UpSpring, removed it again as the end result will be a self containing library somewhere opensourced, yet I don't have any problems without going with a "pimpl" I just learned from Qt at it's nice.

I heard the main advantage of using Pimpl is that it allows me to hide code from headers, which means I have abi compatibility.

They also say it give's fast copy, which isn't relevant in my case as I only have a struct pointer to some "archive" internal data.

Answer (score 2):

The header has unnecessary includes - it certainly doesn't need `<string>` or `<memory>`, and we should be able to forward-declare `std::filesystem::path`.

Avoid making namespace aliases in your headers - you'll end up colliding with some other header's aliases one day.  Prefer to keep these aliases private to your implementation (or if you must, keep them in your namespace, rather than the global namespace).

I'm concerned by the raw pointer member in `vfs_archive_pimpl`.  But it seems okay, because it's always null.  I think we can remove that, and remove that source of worry.

`vfs_archive(const fs::path&)` is declared but never defined.  So any client code that calls that constructor will fail to link.

In fact, it seems that the only thing we can do with this class is default-construct, copy and delete.  It's really not very useful at all.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think it's ok to update my original question with your suggestions?

Comment: @jochumdev Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.